# T-SQL row_number without reordering results

Tags: t-sql

I have a table like this on my Sql-Server DB

```
col1   |col2   | 
--------------------
1      |110    |
2      |120    |
3      |110    |
4      |130    |
5      |120    |
...
```

I need a column that indicates (with a progressive number) a change in column col2. I mean

```
col1   |col2   |ID
--------------------
1      |110    |1
2      |120    |2
3      |110    |1
4      |130    |3
5      |120    |2
...
```

I tried ROW_NUMBER, RANK, DENSE_RANK, NTILE but all of those require Order By clause that reorders the table. I need ID to start from 1 and to change if col2 changes, keeping the same values for same values of col2.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

In fact, `DENSE_RANK` should work here:

```sql
SELECT col1, col2, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY col2) AS ID
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY col1;
```

Comment: I don't think so: order by will reorder rows to meet order on col 2 and I don't want it to happen